# How to retrieve JSON result and use it as a variable?

Tags: php, api

I have a php code and want to make the $rate as Last from the request below

https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker

Currently I can manually input the rate but if theres a way to make the rate as the last or last +25% that would be great.

Code attached below

```
    $market='BTC-SC';
    $apikey='abcdefghi';
    $apisecret='abcdefghi';
    $rate=.getJSON("https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=".$market),html(data.result.Last);
    $nonce=time();
    $uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/buylimit?apikey='.$apikey.'&market='.$market.'&quantity=500&rate='.$rate.'&nonce='.$nonce;
    $sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
    $execResult = curl_exec($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

Comment: What is `data.result.last` supposed to be? PHP doesn't use `.` to access fields of an object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `file_get_contents` as a simple way to read from a URL, and `json_decode()` to parse JSON into an object or array. Then use normal PHP object property syntax to access it. PHP uses `->`, not `.`, to access object properties.

```
$json = file_get_contents("ttps://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=".$market);
$data = json_decode($json);
$rate = $data->result->last;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no prior coding experience. Just read up last night as I wanted to make a quick trading bot without logging into the exchange.

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service or programming school. You need to learn the basics, you can't learn to program this way.